# Selenium returns "Element text does not match" even if it does match

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have been using selenium builder to create a few front end user tests and have now come across an issue with verifyText, which I cannot resolve.

On checking the element the below string is found

> Close Recently added item(s)

I expected it to find

> Recently added item(s)

I confirmed the x-path I have passed it is defiantly correct using firefinder. Selenium builder seems to be ignoring the `<span>` tag completely in this case. As a test I changed the string I was looking for to

> Close Recently added item(s)

and the same message was returned saying

> Elements text "Close Recently added item(s)" does not match "Close Recently added item(s)".

```
<div id="topCartContent" class="block-content" style="overflow: visible;">
    <div class="inner-wrapper" style="">
        <p class="block-subtitle">
            <span class="close-btn" onclick="TopCart.hideCart()">Close</span>
            Recently added item(s)
        </p>
        <p class="cart-empty"> You have no items in your shopping basket. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have successfully confirmed the value in the `<span>` tag so why am I unable to confirm the value in the `<p>` tag?

```
//div[1]/header/nav/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/p[1]/span <!--returns Close-->
//div[1]/header/nav/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/p         <!--returns Close Recently added item(s)-->
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to evaluate your xpath from the fragment of HTML you provided . Using this fragment I managed to find 'Close' by using `//span[@class='close-btn']`. You can test you xpath queries using next http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tested the x-path in firefinder, isn't that accurate? My question was more aimed at trying to understand why the "Close" string was being read as part of the `<p>` tag and why the `<span>` tag is being ignored, oh and how to resolve it. I am able to target the close button individually, now I need to target the "Recently added item(s)" string

Comment: Sorry, but it is not enough for me to see the fragment provided. If you need to access element but its text use `text()` function (`text()='Recently added item(s)'`)

Answer (score 0):

It's actually nice that it shows the text inside of there.  Let's say you have an iframe on the page.  I love that you can get the text of everything in that iframe and search through it. That's just how it works from what I've seen.

As far as comparing the two, I suspect it's a whitespace issue.  Try storing what you get back with a variable then doing a split by ' '.  Often I'll see two spaces which the browser hides.  Saving it in a variable allows you to enter debug mode and watch that variable.  The stack should tell you exactly what's there.